# Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <img>

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in programming, and when I trying to add some images in my JS project.

When I try to run this, I see a message

```
Line 52:24:  Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <img>. (52:24)
```

[image]

By the way, on this line I have next code:

```
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import styles from '../../Styles/Styles.module.scss';

import React from "react";

export const HomePage = () => {

            const navigate = useNavigate()
            const navigateToConsultPageHandler = () => {
                navigate('/Consult', {replace: true});
            }
            const navigateToHomePageHandler = () => {
                navigate('/', {replace: true});
            }
            const navigateToMeditationPageHandler = () => {
                navigate('/Meditations', {replace: true});
            }
            const navigateToSthPageHandler = () => {
                navigate('/sth', {replace: true});
            }
            const navigateToSth2PageHandler = () => {
                navigate('/sth2', {replace: true});
            } //функционал кнопок

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    HomePage
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={navigateToHomePageHandler}>
                        Домашняя страница
                    </button>

                    <button  onClick={navigateToConsultPageHandler}>
                        Страница 1
                    </button>
                    <button  onClick={navigateToMeditationPageHandler}>
                        Страница 2
                    </button>
                    <button  onClick={navigateToSthPageHandler}>
                        Страница 3
                    </button>
                    <button  onClick={navigateToSth2PageHandler}>
                        Страница 4
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel_mp">
                    <div className="carousel-inner_mp">

                        <div className="carousel-item_mp">
                            <img src="Images_mp/Sectificates/1.jpg" alt={"Евразийская ассоциация регрессологов"} />
                            <img src ="Images_mp/Sectificates/2.jpg" alt={"Евразийская ассоциация регрессологов"}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
};
```

I'm already try any ways to close `<img>` I know, such as `<img />` or `<img></img>`

Does anybody know some ways to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9K1K.png)

Comment: Nothing aligns with column 24 in the code provided. Shouldn't need the `{}` around the second `alt` property, though. Are you sure the error isn't from somewhere else?

Comment: Anyway it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Didn't think it would. The issue is that the error message posted doesn't align with anything in the source posted--I'm not sure how anyone can help.

Comment: Please add more code and line numbers.

Comment: Redacted. Added all code and screenshot of error message

Comment: Are you using TypeScript or some kind of minimizer? It may be that the HomePage.js referred to in the error message is not the same as the code you are showing us. The error, in any case, is wrong. In HTML, there is no need to close the `img` tag; it is a [void element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element).

Comment: If i don't close <img> i will have any more problems. 

In don't using any minimizer

I'm redacted 1st message and add another screenshot of error

Comment: @HereticMonkey you absolutely do have to close it. This is not HTML, it's JSX.

Comment: @Evert Then JSX encourages writing bad HTML. I knew there was a reason I didn't trust it...

Comment: @HereticMonkey again, JSX is not HTML. It's a different language with XML-like rules. Also there is nothing wrong with including a `/` in a self-closing HTML element.

Comment: Anyway what shoud i do to fix it? What closing tag shoud i use?